# What use do the spearmen have in Settlers 3?

Tags: the-settlers-3

The spearmen are just somewhat weaker swordsmen with a bit more range - but does the range justify the power disadvantage at any point?

Comment: Not sure about the settlers, but spearmen are a typical counter to cavalry in strategy games in general.

Comment: @user1337 spear, sword & bow.

Comment: "Spear, sword & bow" what?

Comment: @user1337 Those are the 3 settlers 3 units

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, never build swordsman. Spearman might be slower than swordsman and therefor are less effective vs archers but they are just for tanking damage and the extra damage they do when they are in range is much more effective than the speed of swordsman. In the end archers win battles, at least 3/4 of your army should be archers, the rest spearman as your army grows the amount of archers should grow/increase relatively to spearman.

*Source: I have played settlers 3 online for a long time, I actually stood in the top 10 ranking for a long time. I played mostly big and long random games with peacetime of 45+ minutes though.*

Comment: Those times, waiting 2h for a 20MB update ;-)

Comment: I think you've got a typo there: "never build swordsman. They might be slower then swordsman"

Comment: "They" is refering to spearman but since i agree it looks awkward, i'll edit. Thanks!

Comment: @Reactormonk I almost did that speed in the early 90's sitting on a 14.4k modem uploading and downloading stuff from bullitin board systems (3 hour for 20MB), that was before public internet. At the time settlers was out i was sitting on broadband cable of 10Mbps max, 20MB would take me anywhere between 20 seconds and a minute back then.

Comment: What do you mean by "tanking damage"?

Comment: @user204793 Like a "Tank" in RPG terms. They can take more damage and act as a meat shield.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sorry but you are wrong on your statement there.

Spearmen are stronger than sword fighters, if your barracks buildings are as evolved as your enemies you will notice that archers are strong against spearmen *(spearmen are slow)*, spearmen beat the hell out of sword fighters *(their melee is stronger)* and sword fighters beat archers *(speed wise, they can get into close contact very easily)*.

Comment: Ok, I've been looking for data to back up my statement on the more damage part, but haven't found it. Would you have a source?